# Read specific file from multiple .gz file in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.3

I am trying to read a file with a specific name which exists in multiple .gz files within a folder.
 For example
`D:/sample_datasets/gzfiles
  |-my_file_1.tar.gz
    |-my_file_1.tar
      |-file1.csv
      |-file2.csv
      |-file3.csv
  |-my_file_2.tar.gz
    |-my_file_2.tar
      |-file1.csv
      |-file2.csv
      |-file3.csv`

I am only interested in reading contents of `file1.csv` which has the same schema across all the `.gz` files.
I am passing the path `D:/sample_datasets/gzfiles` to the `wholeTextFiles()` method in `JavaSparkContext`. However, it returns the contents of all the files in within the tar viz. file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv.
Is there a way I can only read the contents of `file1.csv` in Dataset or an RDD. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since it is zipped, I think you cannot select the internal file.

Comment: @Lamanus I was able to obtain the required records. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to perform the process using the following snippet I used from multiple answers on SO

```
JavaPairRDD tarData = sparkContext.binaryFiles("D:/sample_datasets/gzfiles/*.tar.gz");
JavaRDD tarRecords = tarData.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction, Row>(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Iterator call(Tuple2 t) throws Exception {
        TsvParserSettings settings = new TsvParserSettings();
        TsvParser parser = new TsvParser(settings);

        List records = new ArrayList();
        TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(t._2.open()));
        TarArchiveEntry entry;
        while((entry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
            if(entry.getName().equals("file1.csv")) {
                InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(tarInput);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
                String line;

                while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                    String [] parsedLine = parser.parseLine(line);
                    Row row = RowFactory.create(parsedLine);

                    records.add(row);
                }

                reader.close();
                break;
            }
        }
        tarInput.close();
        return records.iterator();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `*.gz` at the end of the path.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is not about the wildcard character. It is about the file inside the archive.